# Is there any quick way to get the last two characters in a string?

Tags: java

Wondering how to substring the last two characters quickly in Java?

Comment: What behavior do you want if the string is shorter than 2 characters?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The existing answers will fail if the string is empty or only has one character. Options:

```
String substring = str.length() > 2 ? str.substring(str.length() - 2) : str;
```

or

```
String substring = str.substring(Math.max(str.length() - 2, 0));
```

That's assuming that `str` is non-null, and that if there are fewer than 2 characters, you just want the original string.

Answer (score 24):

```
theString.substring(theString.length() - 2)
```

Answer (score 13):

```
String value = "somestring";
String lastTwo = null;
if (value != null && value.length() >= 2) {  
    lastTwo = value.substring(value.length() - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [substring method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) like this::

```
str.substring(str.length()-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted the opposite. I wanted to strip off the last 2 characters in my string. This was pretty simple:

```
String myString = someString.substring(0, someString.length() - 2);
```