# How can I take user input and replace the last 2 digits of the string with a certain character if its a certain letter

Tags: java, string

I'm having a bit of a struggle with this. So far, I've been able to take user input in but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when it comes to replacing the last 2 digits IF they are 'x'.

```
class Main 
{
    public static String problem1_removeChars(String str) {
        Scanner myScanObj = new Scanner(System.in); //Create Scanner Object
        System.out.println("Enter your string: ");
        
        String readInput = myScanObj.nextLine(); //Read The Input
        System.out.println("Your String Is: " + readInput);
        int stringLength = readInput.length(); // Takes length of the users input
        
        if(stringLength >= 2) {
            if (str.charAt(stringLength - 2) == 'x') {
                str = str.substring(0, stringLength - 2) + str.charAt(stringLength - 1);
            }
        }
        if (str.length() >= 1) {
            if (str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'x') {
                str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        // IF the last 2 characters are 'x' THEN replace 'x' with '~nothing~' to remove x
        // return the string!
        return "str"; // FIX ME
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(problem1_removeChars("str"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `return "str"; // FIX ME` to `return str; // FIX ME`

Comment: You're also not modifying the users input (ie `readInput`) but you're modifying the parameter passed to the method, so yep, not sure what's going on

Comment: This is basically what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768517/is-there-any-quick-way-to-get-the-last-two-characters-in-a-string

Comment: `return str.endsWith("xx") ? str.substring(0, str.length() - 2) : str;`

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to do something like this:

```
if (readInput.endsWith("xx"))
    return readInput.substring(0, readInput.length() - 2);
else
    return readInput;
```

You can also use regex:

```
return readInput.replaceAll("xx$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you're basically ignoring the user input (apart from reading the length of the `String`)

So, unless `str` and `readInput` are the same length, you'll run into issues.

Instead, start by removing the input parameter to the method, as it's confusing you.  Replace uses of `str` with `readInput` and return `readInput` at the end

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static String problem1_removeChars() {
        Scanner myScanObj = new Scanner(System.in); //Create Scanner Object
        System.out.println("Enter your string: ");

        String readInput = myScanObj.nextLine(); //Read The Input
        System.out.println("Your String Is: " + readInput);
        int stringLength = readInput.length(); // Takes length of the users input

        if (stringLength >= 2) {
            if (readInput.charAt(stringLength - 2) == 'x') {
                readInput = readInput.substring(0, stringLength - 2) + readInput.charAt(stringLength - 1);
            }
        }
        if (readInput.length() >= 1) {
            if (readInput.charAt(readInput.length() - 1) == 'x') {
                readInput = readInput.substring(0, readInput.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        // IF the last 2 characters are 'x' THEN replace 'x' with '~nothing~' to remove x
        // return the string!
        return readInput; // FIX ME
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(problem1_removeChars());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (readInput.endsWith("xx")) {
    readInput = readInput.substring(0, readInput.length() - 2);
}
```

would surely be enough?